# Exporting SSRS 2012 report with drilldowns to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export, export-to-excel, drilldown

I have an SSRS report that has a matrix with 3 levels of column groups with drilldowns.  When viewed in browser, it shows the totals for Group 1 (topmost group) by default:

[image]

Then it can be expanded to Group 2 and Group 3:

[image]

[image]

When I export it to Excel, however, for each Group 1, it also shows the first value from Group 2 and the first value from Group 3:

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this bizarre behavior and can help me figure this out??

Thank you!

Comment: when you expand the sections of the report in excel are the other totals correct? If so this may be in the limitations of excel as there had to be a physical summation cell and in some cases they display in this sort of way.  The totals are not hidden but simply collapsed and the root of the grouping will always be visible.

Comment: When I expand, the totals for each subgroup are correct.  However, I can never get the totals by the Group1..   I do understand that this is limitation of excel (when I export to PDF, it looks fine).   I'd like to know if there are any workarounds for this.  I'm sure other people had encountered the same issue. Thanks!